# ASP.NET - Prevent duplicate DB transaction on refresh - Multiple Tabs

Tags: asp.net

I have multiple ASP.NET Gridviews on a page, and each has their own Insert/Update/Delete commands.

In order to prevent duplicate DB transactions on page refresh, I am using a Session variable similar to this method here: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdO5a.png) (src: http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=687&pId=4)

That works as intended. The problem is that many of our users have multiple tabs open performing actions on different search criteria. If a user runs a transaction on one tab, then switches to another tab, the  next transaction they attempt will not commit at all. Since the Session variable has now updated from the other tab, it will prevent the transaction thinking it's a page refresh.

I also cannot redirect to the same URL, as I would lose all search criteria and other form values that need to persist on postback.

Any other tips to have an ASP.NET site running in multiple tabs and also preventing duplicate DB transactions?

Comment: Perhaps each tab should have its own unique session variable, that should isolate the events to a specific tab.

Comment: Or perhaps Session is the wrong thing to use, and ViewState or some other method of maintaining state that isn't shared across an entire session is appropriate.

Comment: Giving each tab its own unique session variable is working. I was having trouble with ViewState based on when it's available during the page cycle.